# I cannot print the final array from the subroutine

Tags: c, arrays, subroutine

I need to create a program that can sum N vectors and print the final array, but for example, if I put N = 2, first array (a,b) and second array(c,d) the sum should be (a+c, d+b) but it shows me only (a,b) and gives me an erro. Of course you can only use numbers into the real program, so please, give me some help to find the problem into this code. Thank you. PS:Some quotes are into Portuguese, I'm sorry for that, but it is my native language.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


/*Program that calculate the sum of N float vector, 
by using a subroutine that generate a resultant vector*/


//SUBROTINA
void forca_res(float vet_res[2],float vet[2],int num)
{   
    int i;
    //Calculo do Vetor Resultante
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        vet_res[i] = vet_res[i] + vet[i];
    }
}


//PROGRAMA PRINCIPAL
int main(void)
{
    //Declaracao de variaveis
    int num, dim=2, i, cont=0;
    float *vet_res, *vet;
    vet= (float*) calloc( dim, sizeof(int) );
    vet_res = (float*) calloc( dim, sizeof(int) );

    //Leitura de dados
    printf("Type the number 'N', of the force vectors: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    //Logic
    while (cont != num)
    {
        printf("\nType the elements of the vector:\n");
        for(i=0;i<2;i++)
        {
            scanf("%f", &vet[i]);
        }
        //Chamando a Subrotina
        forca_res(vet_res, vet, num);
        free(vet);
        cont++;
        printf("\nYour resultant vector:\n");
        for(i=0;i<2;i++)
        {
            printf("%f ", vet_res[i]);
        }
    }

    //Imprimindo o Resultado
    printf("\n\nVETOR RESULTANTE:\n");
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        printf("%f", vet_res[i]);
    }

    //Finalizando o Programa
    printf("\n\nFim do Programa!\n");
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not be freeing `vet` until after your while loop, otherwise the 2nd time through the loop, `vet` will be unallocated.

Comment: `vet_res` is initialized by calloc

Comment: But when I did "vet_res = (float*) calloc( dim, sizeof(int) );" instead of using malloc, I thought that calloc could initialize the vet_res with all values equal 0. Am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you were using calloc, will edit that part out.